# coinbase pro API - Can I update open limit orders?

Tags: coinbase-api

not sure this is possible but I'd like a way to update my limit orders that are outstanding in the order book. Is there a way i can reference the order id and modify the price? Otherwise, i find myself canceling the open order, waiting for the cancel, then placing a new limit order.. I'm running a market making algo and need to update my position in the order book every 2 seconds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So far, in the Coinbase pro API **there is no way to update an existing order**.
You necessarily have to delete an existing order and then create a new one.